# Confirming creditcard details on visual basic.net

Tags: vb.net

Say someone purchases something in store and I have set up so the customer receives an e-mail confirming the purchase and date of delivery, I want to put the customers credit card details on the e-mail but i want them to be in the format off ************1234, how would i go about hashing out the first 12 digits and leaving the rest to be seen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the .substring() method on the credit card string to get the last four digits out and prepend those with asterisks as needed.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()

    Dim creditCard As String = "4190050030182223"

    Dim lastFour As String = creditCard.substring(creditCard.length-4)
    Dim asterisks As new String("*"c, creditCard.length - 4);

    Console.WriteLine("Send this: {0}", String.Concat(asterisks, lastFour))
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Thank you just a few minor changes and it worked a dream i was using mail.body with in the code